Spark Large single Parquet file to Delta Failure with Spark SQL
Cluster details

spark 3.4
5 executors
nodes with x16 cores and 112GB RAM

Parquet file details

provided via 3rd party
source file in adls
single 20GB .parquet file
68 million rows
1,599 columns
5034 row groups

I'm trying to write out only a subset of the columns and all rows to a new delta table using Spark SQL.
Although this is a wide file, I'm trying to write out only a subset of the columns and all rows to a new delta table using Spark SQL.
I've noticed that something that should be simple like a simple count(*) causes failure.  I've tried to narrow this down as much as possible into the smallest increment I could think of and it fails.  For example, the following code writing 10 rows of the smallest column, fails:
CREATE TABLE db.my_table
USING DELTA
AS
SELECT  my_teeny_tiny_column
FROM parquet.`abfss://mycontainer@mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/files/myfile.parquet`
LIMIT 10

As I mentioned I don't get any kind of log that I can read through, all I get back from the dead executor is
Container from a bad node: container_1722263226188_0007_01_000003 on host: vm-######. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2024-07-29 20:43:20.686]Container killed on request
I've also tried to write the same file from parquet to parquet but get the same behavior.
I have noticed that if run just the query portion of this, I can display it in the notebook but for some reason, trying to write it doesn't work.
Has anyone had a problem like this that they were able to solve?

The error message

Container from a bad node and Exit status: 143

This issue is realted to memory-related problem with Apache-Spark, when handling big data.
To resolve  memory issues in Spark effectively and understand the underlying processes.
The memoryOverhead in Spark tuning three has key parameters— Cores, Memory, and MemoryOverhead—can significantly improve the chances of your job succeeding.
MemoryOverhead allows your container (whether it is the driver or executor(s)) to run until its memory usage reaches the MemoryOverhead limit.
As you have mentioned 5 executor nodes each with 16 cores and 112GB RAM, you can configure your Spark settings like below:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Optimized_Spark_dilip")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "4") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "20G") \
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "4")
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "4G")    \
    .config("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "2G") \
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "20")
    .config("spark.default.parallelism", "128") \
    .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.parquet("<Path/to/sample.parquet")
df_subset = df.select("my_teeny_tiny_column").limit(10)
df_subset.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("db.my_table")

Reference: Spark – Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
Here is the below configuration i have tried
For spark.executor.memory

Allocate 20GB per executor.
Calculation:

100GB4 executors per node=25GB per executor\frac{100 \text{GB}}{4 \text{ executors per node}} = 25 \text{GB per executor}
 4 executors per node100GB​=25GB per executor


Reduce for overhead: 25GB−5GB=20GB25 \text{GB} - 5 \text{GB} = 20 \text{GB}25GB−5GB=20GB

For spark.executor.cores
Allocate 4 cores per executor.
spark.executor.memoryOverhead


Set to 10% of 20GB, which is 2GB, or use the default value of 384MB if it is greater.

For spark.executor.instances
Total number of executors:
5 nodes×4 executors per node=20 executors5 \text{ nodes} \times 4 \text{ executors per node} = 20 \text{ executors}5 nodes×4 executors per node=20 executors


Thanks for this, it worked which is awesome.  However, I'm not sure exactly HOW it worked.  Is there some kind of formula of settings that you used to calculate this?  Ideally I would like to scale DOWN my executors to medium (8cores 64GB) each and apply setting such that it would be able to complete using a cheaper set of executors.
